# How are huffman encoded message transmitted across wire?

Tags: java, io

Lets `assume` huffman code for "abcd" was 011011. I need to send this across wire.

My question is `what java's IO mechanism can i use` to

`1. Serialize 011011 on the disk`. For example should it be saved in a file ? bytearray ?

`2. Send  back on the memory`

So this question has more to do with file IO/ and sockets than huffman encoding itself.

I have coded up the huffman tree and generated the codes, I am stuck on the IO and sockets aspect of this problem, of how this `011011` can be sent to receiver.

Answer (score 4):

The only mechanism you can use is a stream of bytes (for TCP) or packets of bytes (for UDP) so either way you need to turn your information into bytes.

When you write to disk, you also need to write bytes, but you also can perform random access (not that it makes a difference here)

You can't send `011011` as a byte but you can send `00011011` as a byte.